# Displaying CID Embedded Images from outlook email using the API

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I am collecting the content of an email from an office 365 account using the REST API, and then using this to display the email in a separate web based platform via an iframe (to avoid css conflicts).

However, the embedded images and emoticons all appear as broken images because they are CID embedded.

Here's what I get back from the API...

```
<img size="96043" contenttype="image/png" id="img295971" tabindex="0" style="max-width: 99.9%; -webkit-user-select: none;" src="cid:1af2f0cb-83b4-46b7-aad6-8ea69256282c">
```

And here's how it looks if I view the same email in office 365...

```
<img originalsrc="cid:1af2f0cb-83b4-46b7-aad6-8ea69256282c" data-custom="EAMkADc2ZjU0ZjU5LTVmOTAtNDZiZC05ZTMyLWFmYTBmNTBkMTc2NQBGAAAAAACbfH93Aq8QSYpfwBCQxPfnBwDmFINdPPDZS5lgCNopiLnYAAAAAAEMAADmFINdPPHZS5lgCNopiLnYAABYntBTAAABEgAQAOVziLpVtbxHtEZu7MUJkA0%3D" src="service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=EAMkADc2ZjU0ZjU5LTVmOTAtNDZiZC05ZTMyLWFmYTBmNTBkMTc2NQBGAAAAAACbfH93Aq8QSYpfwBCQxPfnBwDmFINdPPDZS5lgCNopiLnYAAAAAAEMAADmFINdPPHZS5lgCNopiLnYAABYntBTAAABEgAQAOVziLpVtbxHtEZu7MUJkA0%3D&amp;X-OWA-CANARY=Dg0nza5wGEudJBx_zc2m9bCVF8Ea6dIYZGUuP-qzYHeYA49c7Ddf2wAF8k5zVa6hpRn6AhTjnaE." id="img295971" style="display: inline; max-width: 100%;">
```

Any ideas about what I need to do to get these images to display?

Comment: I do something like this: get all attachments in directory structure like this

/attachments/[ID_MESSAGE]/[ID_ATTACHMENT]/

So.. now if i found in content body of message cid:"" i search by pattern that cid and search in my folder structure file that matches that cid. Then i use replace whole cid thing with url to that file.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer, but it is how we have handled it. @hom nom is right that each image is attached, with it's CID info.  However, this doesn't per se give you a direct way to display it.  However, the REST data does contain both the AttachmentContent AND the ContentId (CID). So we saved the content to somewhere we could refer to it, then replaced the CID image URL with our local image URL. Would love to hear if anyone had found a better solution.

Specifically:
Fetch the attachments for a message:

```
private List<Attachment> GetMessageAttachments(string messageId, string recipientId)
    {
        IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage newAttachments = null;
        List<Attachment> returnAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var nextRequest = graphClient.Users[recipientId].Messages[messageId].Attachments.Request();
        while (nextRequest != null)
        {
            newAttachments = nextRequest.GetAsync().Result;
            returnAttachments.AddRange(newAttachments);
            nextRequest = newAttachments.NextPageRequest;
        }
        return returnAttachments;
    }
```

Get the content of the attachment:

```
public byte[] GetAttachmentBody(string userId, string messageId, string attachmentId)
    {
        string url = $"Users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}/$value";

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new HttpRequestValidationException($"Invalid response: {response.Content}");
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Content);
    }
```

Further detail at the MS Graph documentation:

- Get Attachments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- File Attachment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get attachments list using message's id. (Do not worry about HasAttachments => false). You will get all CID Embedded Images files.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer might get flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.