# How to parse real src path of img in mail body？

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

On Message Compose，I got the email body，The text contains some image information。How to use img's src attribute let me get real image path？

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
      const itemId = result.value;

      Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, (result) => {
        const token = result.value;

        const apiUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + "/v2.0/me/messages/" + itemId;

        axios
          .get(apiUrl, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            var draftData = response.data.Body.Content;
            console.log(draftData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });
    });
```

I tested calling the above code after adding a few pictures in the message writing scene, and the img of the email body is as follows

```
<img width="450" height="450" id="图片_x0020_2" src="cid:image002.jpg@01D9B4AD.403AFD90" />

<img width="465" height="467" id="图片_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D9B4AC.2C972DA0" />
```

What do I need to do to turn cid... into a real image path？

Comment: Those `cid:` URIs **are** the "real image paths": `cid:` URIs are references to elements in a `multipart` document (i.e. HTML email). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922898/embedding-attached-images-in-html-emails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying CID Embedded Images from outlook email using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612576/displaying-cid-embedded-images-from-outlook-email-using-the-api)

Answer (score 0):

`src="cid:xyz"` refers to the message attachment with the matching value of the `Content-ID` MIME property (corresponds to the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENTID` MAPI property).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I still don't quite understand, can you give me the specific code for reference?

Comment: There is no path. The image is included as an attachment. You need to loop through the attachments and grab its data.